# Need to View/Convert .bak file contents

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I've got a .bak file from an HR software we used to use and have been asked to review the contents. I've never done this before, so I've pieced things together from research. So far, I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2 w/ Management Studio and managed to Restore the database from the .bak file.

I've got it in there, but don't know what I'm looking at, how to get the data in a viewable format, export it as .sql, .csv or anything. Not really sure what the next step is to view this in an understandable format. Need a push in the right direction.

Comment: You are no longer dealing with .bak file. Congratulations! you have a database now. Open databases folder using the tree, open tables and you will be able to see all tables. Right click on any table and choose select top 1000 to view data in tables. You need to know SQL to better extract and link your tables.

Comment: So what's my next step to get the data into a format we can understand/review?  Like maybe an Excel spreadsheet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your knowledge with databases, I suggest you follow the following steps to extract a table to Excel

1. From object explorer, open databases by clicking the plus sign on Databases folder

   2. You will see many databases. Click the plus sign for any of them.
   3. Open a folder called Tables, you will see the data tables in that database.
   4. Click on `CTLR + N` with the database name selected.
   5. A query editor will open. Type `SELECT * FROM TableName`. You need to replace `TableName` with the Name of the table you want to explore.
   6. Click `F5`. This will display data for you in a grid at the bottom.
   7. Right click on the top left of the data that you see and click on Copy with Header.
   8. Go to an excel sheet and paste the data.

This is the way to do it table by table. But you are highly encouraged to consult with a database developer or colleague with database knowledge if you want to learn how to manipulate data inside management studio. 
This Link might be helpful for you http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp

Hope this will help.